# How to transpose all subfields in front of the parent field of a pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a data of automotive spare parts with their multiple store locations in a warehouse.
all I want to do is get the locations in front of the part number, so that it is easy to know all the locations of a specific part number.

The current pivot data looks like this
[image]

I've manually transposed a few rows in the below image, but the data contains around 70K rows, Hence I'm looking for a better solution

[image]

Kindly refer to the below table

```
+--------------+-----+-------+-------------+
|  Item name   | Qty |  UoM  |    Stock    |
+--------------+-----+-------+-------------+
| '0450000115  | 324 | piece | G12B04      |
| '0450000A61  | 312 | piece | G12B05      |
| '0450000115  | 336 | piece | G12B06      |
| '0450000A61  | 228 | piece | G12B07      |
| '0450000115  | 336 | piece | G12B08      |
| '0450000115  | 192 | piece | G12B09      |
| '087902E200A | 470 | piece | G12B10      |
| '087902E200A | 760 | piece | G12B13      |
| '087902E200A | 759 | piece | G12B14      |
| '0450000115  | 336 | piece | G12B15      |
| '087902E200A | 400 | piece | G12B16      |
| '087902E200A |  10 | piece | G3B32       |
| '084B410426  | 100 | piece | G3B32       |
| '087902E200A | 300 | piece | G4B08       |
| '0450000A61  |   2 | piece | GDB01       |
| '084B410426  |  60 | piece | GR.04.C.04. |
| '087902E200A | 327 | piece | HD.03.K.05. |
+--------------+-----+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: I am not sure there is an easy way to achieve EXACTLY what you want. However, if you select your Pivot Table and select Report Layout in the Design tab of the ribbon, you can display the table in Compact, Outline and Tabular layouts. You can also choose to repeat item labels. Tabular or Outline look like they would work for your purposes.

Comment: Do you have to use `Pivot Table`? You could easily achieve this with **`VLookUp`** or **`Index + Match`**

Comment: The item name is redundant, vlookup or index match would only fetch the first match. What about the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a measure, using the CONCATENATEX function. For this you need to add your data to the datamodel. You can do this by checking the box `add this data to the datamodel` on the bottom of the `create pivottable` dialogbox.

[image]

Rightclick the table on the Pivottable Fields Pane and select  `add measure`. Then create the following measure: `= CONCATENATEX('table','table'[Stock],", ")`

[image]

Now put [Item name] on Rows and the measure [StockText] on Values. This should be the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million,  @Marco Vos for that perfect solution

Comment: ,In the pivot table without Data Model, I was able sum all the qty, But in the one with the Data Model, Excel throws a warning " We can't summarize this field with Sum because it's not a supported calculation for Text data types."
Why is this such, as the qty has a field type *number*
Nonetheless I tried to overcome this by adding a new measure to convert the qty field to number type using value(), but it still throws the same msg.

Comment: The datatype of the Qty column is probably text then. You can change this on the home tabe of the  Data Model. To get to the Data Model, select `Manage Data Model` on the Data tab

Comment: You just made my day.
God bless